# Problem uploading binary to appstore

Tags: iphone, submit, app-store, code-signing

Well like many other I encountered some problems while uploading my binary to appstore.
This is the error that I see
"The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

I have :

- created distribution certificate and I have private key in the keychain.
- created the distribution provisioning profile and downloaded it to my computer.
- created distribution configuration, and changed to correct code signing identity 
   in project and target
- product identifier should be correct since my app has identifier.*
- In build log I see 
   CodeSign build/Distribution-iphoneos/Service_Live.app with correct paths
   ProcessProductPackaging Service_Live/build/Distribution-
     phoneos/Service_Live.app/embedded.mobileprovision
- I have restarted xcode several time and even recreated the project.

Any idea what the problem is or at least how I can find will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem.
The solution is that I was missing CFBundleResourceSpecification definition inf info.plist.
The more important thing is that I found what the reason for failure by using ApplicationLoader. It is supplied by Apple and for some reason is not referenced as tool to get an indication of what the problem is, though it is.
You can read about applicationloaded in this link http://iosdevelopertips.com/tools/application-loader.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Apple WWDR certificate installed?

If not, you should be able to download and install it from the Certificates section in the iPhone Developer Program portal.

Comment: I have verified it once again and I do have WWDR certificate.